# Is there any significance to the names of the painters listed in Lolita?

Tags: vladimir-nabokov, lolita, art-history

In part 2 chapter 12 of Lolita, Humbert buys her a book about "modern American painting" and attempts to discuss some of the artists with her. The conversation is not a success but I found it noteworthy that Nabokov name-drops four particular real-life painters:

> she wanted to know if the guy noon-napping on Doris Lee’s hay was the father of the pseudo-voluptuous hoyden in the foreground, and could not understand why I said Grant Wood or Peter Hurd was good, and Reginald Marsh or Frederick Waugh awful.

Is there any significance to these four, and to the observation that two are "good" and two are "awful"?

Comment: There's a fifth painter in that paragraph — [Doris Lee,](https://www.memphisflyer.com/simple-pleasures-the-art-of-doris-lee) whose painting *Noon* (fifth from the top in the link) is described.

Comment: I mean, admittedly they’re not Picasso, but nevertheless those painters are *all* pretty significant ….